# How to Set topN via nutch crawl SCRIPT

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to crawl a webpage whose url is http://def.com/xyz/(say) which has more than 2000 outgoing urls, but when I query the solr it is showing less than 50 documents whereas I am expecting around 2000
documents. 
I am using the Following query :

```
./crawl urls TestCrawl http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 2 -topN 3000
```

The console output is :

```
Injector: starting at 2014-12-08 21:36:15
Injector: crawlDb: TestCrawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: Total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
Injector: Total number of urls after normalization: 1
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: overwrite: false
Injector: update: false
Injector: URLs merged: 1
Injector: Total new urls injected: 0
Injector: finished at 2014-12-08 21:36:18, elapsed: 00:00:02
```

I am assuming that somehow nutch is not being able to get topN value from crawl script.

Comment: "Injector: Total new urls injected: 0". Could you please show all console output? the output you showed only for inject job.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the property `db.max.outlinks.per.page` in the nutch configuration.
Change this value to a higher number or to `-1` to have all the urls crawled and indexed.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do